# Регулярное выражение для реврайта в Nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

#### Пытаюсь настроить Nginx так, чтобы все url без слеша на конце он редиректил на url со слешем. А конкретно, мне нужно регулярное выражение для реврайта. Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Есть такой вариант - `^([^.]*[^/])$`. Но он не работает, если ссылка будет с параметром.
То есть, вот, как мне надо:

- `/page` -> `/page/`
- `/page/` - не трогать
- `/file.txt` - не трогать
- `/page?param=val` -> `/page/?param=val`
- `/page/?param=val` - не трогать

Comment: По каким условиям определяется отсутствие слеша? Из примеров только понятно, что конец строки, если не `.txt`, либо перед `?`

Comment: @dIm0n, видимо если это файл, т.е. точка и расширение, то ничего не делать. Хотя может я не прав. Ждем коммент автора